# How can I get a specific layer weights from openvino model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, openvino

I have a trained model and I wand to get, for example, a convolution layer weight matrix.

```
net = ie.read_network(model='model.xml', weights='model.bin')
ie.set_config(config={"CPU_THREADS_NUM": str(4)}, device_name="CPU")
exec_net = ie.load_network(network=net, device_name="CPU", num_requests=1)
```

Where the weights are stored?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommend to use the nGraph function's *get_ordered_ops()* method to get a topologically sorted list of its graph Nodes.

```
import ngraph as ng
function = ng.function_from_cnn(net)
for node in function.get_ordered_ops():
      print('Node name: {:15} Friendly name: {:10} Op: {:10} {}'.format(node.name, node.get_friendly_name(), node.get_type_name(), node.shape))
```

Comment: You can refer to [nGraph’s Python API](https://docs.openvino.ai/2021.4/openvino_docs_nGraph_DG_PythonAPI.html) for more examples.